# To prove subspace of given vector space of functions

Tags: vector-spaces

V is the set of all real-valued functions defined and continuous on the closed interval [0,1] over the real field.
 Prove/disapprove whether the set of all functions  W belonging to V, which has a local extrema at x=1/2, is a vector space or not.

P.s : I am confused at second derivative test, as the linear combinations of 2 functions may result in a function whose second derivative at x=1/2 is zero.

Comment: what does you mean you are confused with the second derivative test ? Looking like it is a vector subspace of the vector space V.

Comment: Do you mwan that $1/2$ is a critical point?

Comment: let's suppose f and g are two functions belonging to W and a,b belongs to field. Since both have a extrema at x=1/2, at their second derivative is greater or less than zero. But a*f + b*g may have second derivative equal to zero.

Comment: yes. x =1/2 is a critical point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=(x-1)(2x-1)^2$ and $g(x)=x(2x-1)^2$.

Then $f^{\prime}(x)=(2x-1)(6x-5)$ and $g^{\prime}(x)=(2x-1)(6x-1)$,

so $f$ and $g$ are both in W $\;\;$(since f has a local max. at $\frac{1}{2}$ and g has a local min. at $\frac{1}{2}$).

However, $f+g$ is not in W,

since
$(f+g)(x)=(2x-1)^3$ and $(f+g)^{\prime}(x)=6(2x-1)^2,\;$
so $f+g$ is always increasing.

Therefore W is not a subspace of V.

Comment: well $(f+g)'(\frac{1}{2})=0$ and so $f+g\in W$, right ?

Comment: @MohamadMisto No, I don't think so; the tangent line to the graph of $f+g$ is horizontal at $(1/2,0)$, but $f+g$ doesn't have a local extremum at $1/2$

Comment: i thought he asked for only a critical point idk thats why i asked

Answer (score 0):

Let $h: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be defined by

$\tag 1 x \mapsto x - \frac{1}{2}$

Define $f(x) = \text{max}\big(h(x),0\big)$ and $g(x) = \text{min}\big(h(x),0\big)$.

We have $f,g \in W$.

The function $f + g$ is equal to $h$ but $h \notin W$.